# Fetch posts from db-table, do math and THEN sort <- how?

Tags: php, javascript

For fetching some db-posts (int) and then multiplying with user input-values I use php.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table")or die("Error" . mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $value1=$row['value1'];
        $value2=$row['value2'];
        $value3=$row['value3'];
        $product1=$value1*$userinput1;
        $product2=$value2*$userinput2;
        $product3=$value3*$userinput3;
     }
```

[Now show results sorted by e.g. product1 ASC]

HOW?

Also how to make it possible to let the user change to e.g. sort by product2?

How can I then show the results, sorted by the sum of the user in put and one value from the row. And also give the user the possibility to change which value and user-input sum to sort by.

Comment: Solution was o fetch from db and create a multi layer array and then perform, where "jmt_tal" is the index I want to sort by. function compare($x, $y){
 if ( $x["jmf_tal"] == $y["jmf_tal"] )
  return 0;
 else if ( $x["jmf_tal"] < $y["jmf_tal"] )
  return -1;
 else
  return 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `value1`*' . intval($userinput) . ' ASC')
```

Comment: Yes that is the way to sort the data from the mysql. I need to take that data, multiply it with some user input and THEN I need to sort it. Any thoughts?